# Objects into functions

Tags: object, linear-programming, paradigms, structured-programming

I have a question that my teacher asked me and I could not find the answer, I am still searching in pdf for public institutions how mit (which are public), utn or related, if anyone can answer me or tell me where I can find it, thank you.

Objects within a function? Utility and performance
(Comparison of linear programming and structured programming paradigms)

Comment: That's a series of questions that you clearly copied and pasted - explain it to us in your own words (providing relevant context and/or examples) so we (and you) can better understand it.

Comment: I didn't copy anything, I really searched a lot, and the question my teacher asked me is like this (in Spanish, my mother tongue). That is why I clarified below that I was comparing the paradigms of linear and structured programming. The question seems absurd to me, but to be sure, he asked around here. And what I pose is, literally, how the question is asked, without any example, since it is a research work in which the last point is this

Comment: There's a Spanish version of StackOverflow - you might be able to explain your problem easier there: https://es.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thank you, but I decided to ask this question here, since these parts are more receptive in regards to questions of this nature.